# after joining 2 tables on one to many type of relationship can i display the data on each individual join condition

Tags: mysql, join, select, subquery

[image]

given the schema the client.accountNumber is reference for both sender and reciepient of table package.
I want to use the select query in such a way that it shows recipient(reference client table) and sender name(reference client table) in different columns

```
select Name_client as sender_name,Name_client as reciepint_name from package
join shipment on Shipment_=ShipmentID
join client on AccountNumber=sender or AccountNumber=recipient
join employee on employeeID=manager;
```

something like this code but the recipient and sender name in different columns

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second join to the Client table -

```
select c1.Name as SenderName, c2.Name as RecipientName
from Package p
join Shipment s on p.Shipment = s.ShipmentID
join Client c1 on p.Sender = c1.AccountNumber
join Client c2 on p.Recipient = c2.AccountNumber
join Employee e on s.Manager = e.EmployeeID;
```